# Campgrounds in the United Kingdom

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uk

I'm looking for a dataset with campgrounds in the United Kingdom that I can load into a handheld Garmin GPS-receiver.  Openstreetmap includes some, but it is not complete and it is not easy to search specifically for campgrounds.  Is there such a database?

Comment: I got looking at Openstreetmap and noticed some camp sites are identified as a point, others are polygons labelled as camp sites. To capture all the data tagged as camp sites it may be necessary that you search for points and polygons?

Answer (score 3):

I am not an OSM expert but doesnt this API call do what you want?

http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/a8X

[Here is a gist of the results of the API call:](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/07ad75898863e4357813)

```
/*
This query looks for nodes, ways and relations 
with the given key/value combination.
Choose your region and hit the Run button above!
*/
[out:json][timeout:60];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “tourism=camp_site”
  node["tourism"="camp_site"](49.696061819115634,-10.6787109375,59.28833169203345,2.012695312500001);
  way["tourism"="camp_site"](49.696061819115634,-10.6787109375,59.28833169203345,2.012695312500001);
  relation["tourism"="camp_site"](49.696061819115634,-10.6787109375,59.28833169203345,2.012695312500001);
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```